# How to get ViewModel in BottomSheetDialog

Tags: java, android, mvvm, architecture, components

I need to refer to ViewModel in my BottomSheetDialog. I didn't find any solution how to do it. So, I decided to make **wordViewModel** static field. I don't know if it is correct way.

The problem is that I can not pass a Lifecycler owner to ViewModelProvider.
I tried like this in BottomSheetDialog.class, but this line throws an exception:

```
wordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel.class);
```

The following solution hepled me.

MainActivity.class

```
public static WordViewModel wordViewModel;

wordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel.class);
```

BottomSheetDialog.class

```
@OnClick(R.id.findBtn)
    void findWordDefinition(){

        String mWord = wordText.getText().toString();
        MainActivity.wordViewModel.getWord(mWord);
        dismiss();
    }
```

Please explain how to solve it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

BottomSheetDialogFragment is just like other fragment.so you can use requireActivity() to get life cycle owner.

```
wordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(WordViewModel.class);
wordViewModel.getWord(mWord);
```